# Rearranging Frogs

Tags: strategy

This is a small puzzle that I saw a lot as a kid but surprisingly haven't found on this site. Enjoy!

---

You have six frogs arranged on seven lily pads in a line: three male frogs facing right on the leftmost lily pads and three female frogs facing left on the rightmost lily pads.

> M M M _ F F F

How can you switch the positions of the frogs (have the male frogs end up where the female frogs currently sit and vice versa)?

Rules:

- Each lily pad can hold only one frog.
- Frogs can only move in the direction they are facing.
- Frogs can move forward to an empty lily pad or jump over one frog to the empty lily pad on the other side.

Comment: @JonTheMon There's the duplicate I was looking for. The wording of that one was very poor, though...

Comment: Also once you have the idea, 5 on each side is a bit more of a grind problem.

Comment: Is it really a duplicate?  In the other question only one merchant's camels can jump, but here frogs from each side can jump.

Comment: It's essentially the same question, but I'm just surprised the camels can jump at all :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic idea:

> They need to try to mix perfectly - MFMFMF

Process:

> MMM_FFF
> MM_MFFF
> MMFM_FF
> MMFMF_F
> MMF_FMF
> M_FMFMF
> _MFMFMF
> FM_MFMF
> FMFM_MF
> FMFMFM_
> FMFMF_M
> FMF_FMM
> F_FMFMM
> FF_MFMM
> FFFM_MM
> FFF_MMM

Also, I'm also surprised this isn't on the site already in a different form. It's quite possible that I just didn't search for the right terms.

Comment: Out of the three answers there's a 17 move, 16 move, and 15 move. I think yours is the most efficient possible (and first before going's edit) so +1 and probably should be accepted.

Comment: @Quark you mean 2 15s and a 17

Comment: @JLee the other 15 had duplicated a line, making it look like a 16.

Comment: Woopsie daisies...

Answer (score 2):

> MMM_FFF
>  MMMF_FF
>  MM_FMFF
>  M_MFMFF
>  MFM_MFF
>  MFMFM_F
>  MFMFMF_
>  MFMF_FM
>  MF_FMFM
>  _FMFMFM
>  F_MFMFM
>  FFM_MFM
>  FFMFM_M
>  FFMF_MM
>  FF_FMMM
>  FFF_MMM !

Comment: Nice job. This looks optimal.

Comment: Honestly I am fairly certain there could only ever be 1 way to do this as how in I am approaching it you are forced as if you go one move rather than another it always cuts off the other move.